# Get column name from dataframe as string

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, string, dataframe

How can I take a name of column in dataframe from list and add it to text?

```py
column=[df['o2_dry'],df['co2_dry'],df['co_ppm_dry'],df['no_ppm_dry'],df['velocity-magnitude']]


for i in range(5):
    axs[i].title.set_text('Graph for '+ str(column[i]))
```

**The result should be:**

```
Graph for o2_dry

Graph for co2_dry
```

Etc.

Comment: What is the problem actually ? In `column` you don't put the name of the column, but the values itself are you aware of that ? Do you want tp have both name and values ?

Comment: @azro it "prints" values in rows from columns. I want to have only names of columns

Comment: You can't take the column name from YOUR list, as your list contains only Series (values), what do you really want to do at the end ? Iterate over both column name+values ?

Comment: @azro My `column` is used for values and now I want to use it for name of these columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `df[name]` returns a `Series` you can get both the values and its name (using `.name`)

```
columns = [df['o2_dry'],df['co2_dry'],df['co_ppm_dry'],df['no_ppm_dry'],df['velocity-magnitude']]
    
for i in range(5):
    axs[i].title.set_text('Graph for '+ column[i].name)
```

---

But the nicer would be

```
columns = ['o2_dry', 'co2_dry', 'co_ppm_dry', 'no_ppm_dry', 'velocity-magnitude']
    
for idx, column in enumerate(columns):
    axs[idx].title.set_text('Graph for '+ column)
    values = df[column]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `columns[i].name` to get the name. Note that `columns` is a list of pandas.series objects.

Comment: I know, but in my code I want to take names of columns from list `column`

Comment: Ah! You can use `column[i].name` to get the name of the column.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly after reading your dataframe, you can get column names using variable_name.columns.tolist() where varibale name is name assigned to your dataframe.
for eg:

```
        df = pd.read_csv(path_to_file)
        column_name_list = df.columns.tolist()
```

then column name list will contains all column names, just loop over this list and print.